# Delphi & OSX - Deploy Unix Executable with App Bundle

Tags: macos, delphi, deployment

Here's the set up I'm trying to sort out -

I'm working on an application which is primarily a .dylib

To run this .dylib, I've created a small application with xcode.  What I want to do is distribute this application along with my Delphi project as part of the application bundle. When I fire up the remote debugger, I want Delphi to use the xcode application as the "Host Application".

So, I think I've set everything up.  I copied the xcode application over to my windows machine, and inserted it into my project's "Deployment" menu, so that it appears in "Contents\MacOS" inside of the app bundle.

Unfortunately, upon deployment, something seems to get lost.  Either the file does not have it's executable flag set, or it's resource tree has gone missing.  Is there any way to set up Delphi so that it can properly deploy a "unix executable file"?

(One note - I did check to make sure that the file was not damaged / modified by moving it over to a windows machine.  The issue seems to take place at deployment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PAClient seems to change permissions depending upon what "mode" the files are sent under.  Here's a quick workaround:

**If you want to use PAClient to Deploy an Executable File:**

```
paclient.exe --put="PathToFileOnLocalMachine\filename,PathToFileOnOSXMachine\,1,filename
```

To send as an executable, make sure that you use "1" in the command.

**If you want to trick Delphi into deploying an executable for you:**

Open up your .dproj file inside of a text editor.  Locate the listing for the file you are trying to deploy.  Look for this specific line:

```
<DeployFile LocalName="FileName" Class="File">
```

and switch the Class from "File" to "ProjectOutput".

Now Delphi will deploy the executable properly.